# robolectric doesn't use ~config-package namespace attribute

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, github, robolectric

I want to add robolectric to an existing and live android-dagger project

The problem is that the package name in the AndroidManifest is not aligned with the R file physical path.

robolectric searches for the R file according to the manifest "package_name" attribute.

I thought to use @Config over my robolectric test

```
@Config(manifest = " --my---path/AndroidManifest.xml",
        sdk = 21,
        packageName = "com.google.andorid.apps.ridematch",
        application = TestApplication.class)
```

but apparently the "packageName" annotation is not effective.

I wanted to debug this in the robolectric open source,
but wasn't sure where was the problematic code.

It was a chance for me to first contribute to a github open-source project

my tries:

try 1)
I thought the bug is in code:

```
@Test
  public void shouldAssignThePackageNameFromTheManifest() throws Exception {
    AndroidManifest appManifest = newConfigWith("com.wacka.wa", "");
    Application application = defaultTestLifecycle.createApplication(null, appManifest, null);
    shadowOf(application).bind(appManifest, null);

    assertThat(application.getPackageName()).isEqualTo("com.wacka.wa");
    assertThat(application).isExactlyInstanceOf(Application.class);
  }
```

so I wrote this code:

```
  @Test
      public void shouldAssignThePackageNameFromConfigWhenHaveConfigAndManifest() throws Exception {
        AndroidManifest appManifest = newConfigWith("com.wacka.wa", "");

        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("packageName", "com.robolectric.MyTestClass");
        properties.put("application", "com.robolectric.TestTestApplication");
    //    properties.put("application", "FakeApp");

        Config config = Config.Implementation.fromProperties(properties);
        Application application = defaultTestLifecycle.createApplication(null, appManifest, config);
        shadowOf(application).bind(appManifest, null);

        assertThat(application.getPackageName()).isEqualTo("com.robolectric.MyTestClass");
        assertThat(application).isExactlyInstanceOf(TestTestApplication.class);
      }
```

In "bind" i made non null config-package name override appManifest package name.

but I couldn't find who calls "defaultTestLifecycle.createApplication"

try 2)
I started looking at this class and its tests:

```
 @Override
  protected AndroidManifest getAppManifest(Config config) {


I saw this test:



     @Ignore
      @Config(constants = BuildConfig.class, packageName = "fake.package.name")
      public static class PackageNameTest {

        @Test
        public void withoutAnnotation() throws Exception {
        }
      }
```

and I have added mine:

```
     @Ignore
      @Config(constants = BuildConfig.class, packageName = "fake.package2.name", manifest = "//java/com/google/android/apps/ridematch/environments/debug:AndroidManifest.xml")
      public static class PackageNameConfigAndManifestTest {

        @Test
        public void withoutAnnotation() throws Exception {
        }
      }
```

but the test passed, so the bug is not there.

Comment: I'm asking again, why not to use `RobolectricGradleTestRunner`?

Comment: as seen by all tutorials. no?